# Gravity forms dynamically populate dropdown with parameter

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity Forms on my wordpress website. I wanted to use dynamically populated fields and also need to auto selected with parameter.

**My problem is
I need to pass the post id from url. but when user submit the form , need to send the post title as the value.**

Eg : myurl/?staff_member=14

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_2', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_2', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_2', 'populate_posts' );


function populate_posts( $form ){

  foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
    if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
      continue;
    }

    $posts = get_posts(array(
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_type'     => 'staff',
    ));

    $choices = array();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $choices[] = array( 
        'text'  => $post->post_title, 
        'value' => $post->ID, //** <- I am using post ID , because url parameter need to be the post id. also i need to send post title when submit the form
      );
    }

    $field->placeholder = 'Select Staff Member';
    $field->choices = $choices;
  }

  return $form;

}
```

Comment: So here you want post tile in email that is the only thing right ?

Comment: @dipmala Yes,  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can change field value while sending the email , that can be possible using `gform_notification` filter, kindly check below code for the same.

```
    add_filter( 'gform_notification_1', 'change_notification_email', 10, 3 ); // here 1 is my form id, change with your form id
    function change_notification_email( $notification, $form, $entry ) {

        if ( $notification['name'] == 'Admin Notification' ) 
        { 
            $fieldid=2;
            $postid=$entry[$fieldid]; // here 2 is my field id change with your field id
            $entry[$fieldid] =get_the_title($postid); // this will change the field value in email.
        }

        return $notification;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. Appreciate your answer,

Comment: This is works for me. Thank you very much !!!
Really appreciate your help.